Keycloak exception: Frame type length exceeds MAX_FRAME_SIZE
I have created a custom keycloak SPI API for some authorization purposes. So, inside this custom API I am calling one keyclaok admin API ({{base_path}}/admin/realms/{{realm_name}}/clients/{{client_id}}/authz/resource-server/policy/evaluate), to fetch the authorization information.
But whenever I am getting response and load is high, I am getting below response,
[com.feathersoft.keycloak.organization.api.OrganizationController] (executor-thread-541) Exception customIntrospect: java.io.IOException: protocol error: Frame type(114) length(7565173) exceeds MAX_FRAME_SIZE(16384)

The code i am calling this API is,
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(api))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authData)
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
        .build();
return client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

Can anyone advise me, what should I do to avoid this issue?
